# STM32F4 waveshare xcore407l doesn't work on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ram, stm32, flash-memory

During three days I try to program and flash my STM32F4 waveshare xcore407l development board (bought on amazon) but I cannot do it.It doesn't work I tried to flash it with stm32flash and st-flash but I get some error.
When I try with stm32flash (stm32flash -w test.bin -v -g 0x8000000 /dev/ttyS0) I get output error like :

```
Using Parser : Raw BINARY
Warning: Not a tty: /dev/ttyS0
Error probing interface "serial_posix"
Cannot handle device "/dev/ttyS0"
Failed to open port: /dev/ttyS0
```

with st-flash (st-flash write v1 test.bin  0x8000000) I get this:

```
2016-04-16T16:47:39 WARN src/stlink-sg.c: Failed to find an stlink v1 by VID:PID
2016-04-16T16:47:39 ERROR src/stlink-sg.c: Could not open stlink device
```

if someone has already worked on this development board thanks to tell me how you did it. 
Pending your answers I wish you good day

Answer (score 0):

I got same error. So you should use `sudo`:

> >sudo stm32flash /dev/ttyUSB0